# Type Markdown and LaTeX: 2 error in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I have written Python in Jupyter Notebook but I have never got an error of this sort before. I am not sure why it says "Type Markdown and LaTeX:  2 error". I have used pandas.read_excel() to read my xlsx files previously. But, of late I realize that xlrd has stopped supporting xlsx files. Therefore, I installed the openpyxl engine.

This is not much of an error in the code since the pandas function does its job of extracting the data from my excel file using the openpyxl engine. However, when I clicked "Run" in Jupyter Notebook it used to run the python interpreter for the line and then open up a new line for me to enter the next set of instructions. But, the message prevents me from writing the next instruction.

What I did differently this particular time is that I created a new conda environment and installed only the packages I require - numpy, matplotlib, scipy, pandas, jupyternotebook, and openpyxl. The package openpyxl was installed separately using conda install openpyxl=2.5.7 to allow pandas to read xlsx file. Pandas required openpyxl > 2.5.7 and conda install openpyxl installed version 2.4.0 from bioconda. Hence, installed with 'conda install openpyxl=2.5.7'

[image: Error Message not permitting me to write the next line of instruction]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You created an empty markdown cell under you `pd.read_excel` cell. Empty markdown cells are automatically rendered with this content when empty.

If you want to edit the content of that cell, double click on it. If you want to change the nature of the cell, go to `Cell > Cell type`

Comment: Thanks. I have no idea how that happened. I thought maybe the function was not running so I tried removing and reinstalling the openpyxl a number of times and could not find any solution on the internet as well. Thanks it is SOLVED now.

Comment: I have the same problem, but even if I changed the cell type it actually adds another cell (with the same output) which i can edit. My main problem is that I cannot reopen previous notebooks...

Comment: Could you explain more on what exactly the message means? I understand that Markdown is a markup language and LaTeX is a typesetting language. Is the message saying that the cell is of the type markdown and LaTeX? If so, then what does the 2 at the end represent?